# Are there GET and POST methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, http, post, get, web-deployment

Is there any way I can use GET and POST methods in JavaScript like in PHP? Of course, I could echo javascript code in script tags using PHP, but in my case that's impossible...

Comment: You should look into ajax: [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) or [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) is what you need. It is a native way to communicate with a server.

Also, thanks to @charlietfl, more modern approach is to use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), but its not supported in IE.

Comment: More modern approach is use `fetch()`

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, you can try **fetch** but the following code sample may also work for you - in the meanwhile. Just call the **ajaxPOST(postParams, url)** with the right parameters.

```
//This function creates cross-browser XMLHttp object
function createXMLHttp(){
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") { 
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {  
        var aVersions = [   "MSXML2.XMLHttp.9.0",
                            "MSXML2.XMLHttp.8.0",
                            "MSXML2.XMLHttp.7.0",
                            "MSXML2.XMLHttp.6.0",
                            "MSXML2.XMLHttp.5.0",
                            "MSXML2.XMLHttp.4.0","MSXML2.XMLHttp.3.0",
                            "MSXML2.XMLHttp","Microsoft.XMLHttp"
                        ];
        for (var i = 0; i < aVersions.length; i++) {
            try {
                var oXmlHttp = new ActiveXObject(aVersions[i]);
                return oXmlHttp;
            } catch (oError) {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }
    }   
    //if it reaches here, this cannot be created
    throw new Error("XMLHttp object could be created.");    
}

//this does Ajax POST
//sample params: var postParams = "key1="+value1+"&key2="+value2+"&keyx="+valuex; 
function ajaxPOST(postParams, url){
    var retString = false;
    //creating xbrowser xmlhttp object; you handle any failures here
    var http = createXMLHttp(); 
    //setting headers
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    //call-back handler
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {      
        if(http.readyState == 4) {
            if(http.status == 200) {
                //this went fine 
            }
            //read results now, you may trim it for extra spaces
            retString = http.responseText;
            //alert("retString: "+ retString); 
        }
        return retString;       
    }
    //send the request
    http.send(postParams);
}
```